# Catch "socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused" exception

Tags: python, sockets

How could I catch `socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused` exception ?

```
try:
    senderSocket.send("Hello")
except ?????:
    print "catch !"
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

By catching *all* `socket.error` exceptions, and re-raising it if the `errno` attribute is not equal to 111. Or, better yet, use the [`errno.ECONNREFUSED`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#errno.ECONNREFUSED) constant instead:

```
import errno
from socket import error as socket_error

try:
    senderSocket.send('Hello')
except socket_error as serr:
    if serr.errno != errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        # Not the error we are looking for, re-raise
        raise serr
    # connection refused
    # handle here
```

Comment: Now when it caught it propts `AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'error'` ... I using `Python 2.6.5` .

Comment: @URL87: Did you do `from socket import socket`? Don't mask the module name with a different object in your code.

Comment: @URL87: you can also do `from socket import error` then `except error, serr:` but that is not as readable. Updated the answer to use a middle ground.

Comment: FYI, If using Python 3.3 it now has `ConnectionRefusedError` and `socket.error` is deprecated.

Comment: `serr.errno` probably only works from python 2.6 onwards, when `socket.error` was made inherit from `IOError`. Prior to that, `serr.args[0]` seems to do the same.