# Errno 61 connection refused for UDP client server application

Tags: python, udp

We are trying to run a simple UDP client server application.

UDPServer.py

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
print "The server is ready to receive"
while 1:
    message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

UDPClient.py

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'servername'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

The server runs first, but the client gets the error 'Errno 61 connection refused', why?

Comment: both the client and server firewalls are off

Comment: and 'servername' is really the server's IP address I just removed it for this question

Comment: I tried the code on my machine and it's working (using 127.0.0.1 as serverName). Probably the IP address is incorrect? Can you give more details on your network setup?

Answer (score 1):

If you run the two program in the same machine, change to client serverName to serverName = 'localhost'. If in two different machines, the serverName should be the server's IP address, and shutdown the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the example out but I had to alter these two lines in the client to get it to run (and then it seems to run fine over a network):

```
import socket
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

However I have seen the 'Errno 61 connection refused' with UDP connections - Which usually indicates an ICMP Destination Unreachable response has been received in reply to a packet sent to an unbound port on the server. But this only results in a Errno 61 with a socket that has called `connect((server,port))`, and which has then been used to `send()` an initial packet, and subsequently (with enough delay for the ICMP packet to be received) calls `recv()` - which raises an exception containing the Errno 61 (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425401/catch-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-exception) to find out how to catch it).