# PYTHON - URLLIB2 Catch socket.error

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, urllib2

Right now I am using urllib to pull some data off a server. However, the server is a bit dodgy and tends to go down every now and then for a minute or so. To deal with, when my code encounters an error, it just waits two seconds and tries again:

```
def fin(group):
try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen("cool website" + group)
    return data.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    time.sleep(2)
    fin(group) #calls itself again
except urllib2.URLError, err:
    time.sleep(2)
    fin(group)
```

That works fine if the website goes down or I lose my internet connection. However, last night I left the code running and got this error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I am not quite sure how to catch that. After some searching I am thinking I may need to do this:

```
except httplib.HTTPException, err:
    time.sleep(2)
    fin(group)
```

But I am not certain. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: what's with the time.sleeps in the exception handlesr?

Comment: Try catching the `socket.error` stated here? http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error

Maybe this would help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425401/catch-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-exception