# Looking for python errno.ECONNREFUSED or ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: python-2.7

I am looking for either of the above two Exceptions but cannot find them. In my existing errno I only have ECONNRESET.

I found a comment about python 3 (maybe time to upgrade?) and ConnectionRefused Error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425401/catch-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-exception)) but I cannot find the library that contains it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch "socket.error: \[Errno 111\] Connection refused" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425401/catch-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see `errno.ECONNREFUSED` in the `socket` module.

`ECONNREFUSED` is not an exception though.  `socket` throws an exception of type [socket.error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error), and sets the `errno` field of the exception to tell you what kind it was.  So you would do the following to check for `ECONNREFUSED`

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect(('myhost', port))
except socket.error as sock_err:
    if(sock_err.errno == socket.errno.ECONNREFUSED):
        print "Connection was refused"
```

You can also see this in the answer [by Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425454/4687135)

Comment: Ok. I'm a bit confused: what is my import? socket? socket.error? what do I put in the except clause? Nothing seems to give me access to errno.ECONNREFUSED. Unless I do: except socket.error:
                    if socket.errno.ECONNREFUSED

Comment: @goggelj I've updated the answer to hopefully help you